# Add class to admin category view for out of stock items

Tags: magento2.4.5

I'd like to be able to add a class to the tiles in category grid view in admin where an item's stock is zero (0). How can I do this?

My goal is for the tiles to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a few more minutes on this and this is the solution I came up with:

I copied this file /vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/view/adminhtml/templates/category/merchandiser/tile.phtml into my custom Admin Theme and added code to check the stock amount. If the stock amount is zero, a class is then created and added to the product-tile.

/app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/AdminTheme/Magento_VisualMerchandiser/templates/category/merchandiser/tile.phtml

```
This code starts at line 80 in tile.phtml.

<?php if ($block->getCollection()): ?>
    <div class="admin__data-grid-wrap admin__data-grid-wrap-static">
        <div class="hor-scroll">
            <ul id="catalog_category_merchandiser_list" class="catalog-category-merchandiser-list">
                <?php foreach ($block->getCollection() as $_index => $_product): ?>
                    <?php /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_item */ ?>
                    <?php
                    // if item is out of stock, add class to grey out tile
                    $oosClass = '';
                    if ($_product->getStock() === '0.0000') {
                        $oosClass = 'item-oos';
                    } ?>
                    <li class="product_tile <?= /* @noEscape */ $oosClass ?>">
                        <div class="controlbar-top">
                            <a href="#" class="icon-gripper"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Draggable')) ?></span></a>
                            <a href="#" class="remove-product icon-close-mage"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Close')) ?></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-holder">
                            <img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl($_product)) ?>" alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Product image')) ?>" />
                        </div>
```

/app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/AdminTheme/web/css/source/_module.less

```
.merchandiser-app {
  .catalog-category-merchandiser-list {
    > li.item-oos {
      background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

To add a custom class to the tiles in the category grid view in Magento admin when an item's stock is zero, you can follow these steps

1.Override the template file:

Create a custom theme or use an existing theme in Magento.
In your theme directory, navigate to the following path: app/design/adminhtml/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/grid.phtml.
If the templates and product directories don't exist in your theme, create them

2.Modify the grid.phtml file

Open the grid.phtml file in a text editor.
Find the loop that iterates through the products and renders the grid tiles. It typically looks like this

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<!-- Render grid tile here -->
```

Inside the loop, you can add custom logic to check if the product's stock is zero (0) and add a class accordingly

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $stock = (int)$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty(); ?>
    <div class="grid-tile<?php if ($stock === 0) echo ' out-of-stock'; ?>">
        <!-- Render grid tile content here -->
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

3.Define CSS for the custom class:

In your theme, create or edit the CSS file that is responsible for styling the admin area. The path to the CSS file is typically: app/design/adminhtml/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/styles.css.
Add the CSS rules to style the tiles with the "out-of-stock"

```
.grid-tile.out-of-stock {
    border: 2px solid red;
   }
```

4.Clear the Magento cache:

After making the above changes, clear the Magento cache to ensure the changes take effect. You can do this by running the following command in the command line

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Ansari. When I look at it, it doesn't look like it is adding the code in the correct file. I was able to come up with another solution that does work for me.